# package models is not in GOROOT when build docker

Tags: docker, go

I found similar issues here in stackoverflow but I sipmly find no solution. Please help.

My go env:

```
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOPATH=C:\Users\[username]\go
set GOROOT=C:\Go
```

And when building go project with docker build -t gotest:vlocal .
I get main.go:7:2: package models is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/models)

but C:\Go\src\models folder exists and **go build main.go** creates the exe in C:\Go\bin, **go run main.go** runs the program.

My docker file

```
FROM golang:1.14.3-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN go build -o /out/example .
FROM scratch AS bin
COPY --from=build /out/example /
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? What does `go env` say? Could you also include the `go env` instruction to your Dockerfile, so that we'll see the setup during the build. Also, post your project structure (in particular, where does your go.mod leave?)